# Ghostscript output to file with ESC-P sequences

Tags: printing, driver, ghostscript, postscript, ppd

For a project (printing nanofluids with an Epson printer) I want to see the the code that the computer sends to the printer. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have an Epson Stylus SX600FW printer.
Using Ghostscript 9.18 I am trying to print a simple file `test.ps` and I want to obtain the output file that is being send to the printer. This file should contain some ESC/P sequences if I am right.

I tried to obtain such a file using:

```
gs -sDevice=epson -sOutputFile=test1output test1.ps
```

Whatever I try, I can't find the output file anywhere, so I doubt it is even created. Then next if I have the output file, how can I read the ESC/P sequences? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output file should be created right in the directory where you are issuing this command, provided that gs does not throw any errors. You will recognize the ESC's in a text editor as somehow marked unprintable or use (unix) `od -t x1 test1output` to find the escapes as 1B hex chars

Comment: I got the file, any suggestion on how to make it a bit more understandable? My ps file makes just a simple line, any way to see what part of the file contains the information that let the printer make a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, that command line results in a file called 'test1output' in the current directory. If you are unable to find the file you could try specifying a complete path and file spec, or at least `-sOutputFile=./test1output`

As for reading the sequences, any binary editor will read the file.

Comment: Could you show the complete input and output of the gs run please?

Comment: [![gs_terminal.jpg](https://s18.postimg.org/wwgg8olc9/gs_terminal.jpg)](https://postimg.org/image/pt8kt2fwl/)

Comment: After showpage I pressed enter, and then typed quit

Comment: I created a virtual machine running Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked. I got some output now. I will reinstall gs

Comment: I reinstalled the newest Ghostscript and now it works on my pc as well.